# How to check if the order of operators in an equation is correct?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a function that takes an equation as input and evaluate it based on the operations, the rule is that I should have the operators(*,+,-,%,^) **between** correct mathematical expressions, examples:

```
Input: 6**8 
Result: Not correct
```

**Reason:** * has another * next to it instead of a digit or a mathematical expression

```
Input: -6+2
Result: Not correct
```

**Reason:** "-" was in the beginning and it didn't fall between two numbers.

```
Input: 6*(2+3)
Result: Correct
```

**Reason:** "*" was next to a mathematically correct expression "(2+3)

Comment: You're explicitly checking that the item to the left and right of the * is a digit, which ( is not.

Comment: This is called "parsing". One way to approach this is to create a grammar for mathematical expressions and then write a parser for that grammar.

Comment: A useful algorithm might be the Shunting-yard-algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Comment: `-6+2` is `-4`, seems a pretty correct result to me...

Comment: @Jan I think the problem is, that the minus '-' is not **between** two expressions

Comment: @UliSotschok: You are right here. I added a parser example for his problem as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Option: eval

`eval` the expression with try-except:

```
try:
    result = eval(expression)
    correct_sign = True
except SyntaxError:
    correct_sign = False
```

Advantages:

- Very easy and fast

Disadvantages:

- Python accepts expressions, that you probably don't want (e.g. ** is valid in python)
- eval is not secure

### 2. Option: Algorithm

In compilers algorithms are used, to make a math expression readable for the pc. These algorithms can also be used to evaluate if the expression is valid. 
I don't aim to explain these algorithms. There are enough resources outside.

This is a very brief structure of what you can do:

- Parsing an infix expression
- Converting infix expression to a postfix expression
- Evaluating the postfix expression

You need to understand what postfix and infix expressions mean.

**Resources:**

Shunting yard algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Reverse polish notation/ post fix notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Python builtin tokenizer: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tokenize.html

Advantages:

- Reliable
- Works for complicated expressions
- You don't have to reinvent the wheel

Disadvantages

- complicate to understand
- complicate to implement

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, this is called `parsing` and requires a grammar.
See an example with [**`parsimonious`**](https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious), a `PEG` parser:

```
from parsimonious.grammar import Grammar
from parsimonious.nodes import NodeVisitor
from parsimonious.exceptions import ParseError

grammar = Grammar(
    r"""
    expr        = (term operator term)+
    term        = (lpar factor rpar) / number
    factor      = (number operator number)

    operator    = ws? (mod / mult / sub / add) ws?
    add         = "+"
    sub         = "-"
    mult        = "*"
    mod         = "/"

    number      = ~"\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
    lpar        = ws? "(" ws?
    rpar        = ws? ")" ws?
    ws          = ~"\s+"
    """
)


class SimpleCalculator(NodeVisitor):

    def generic_visit(self, node, children):
        return children or node

    def visit_expr(self, node, children):
        return self.calc(children[0])

    def visit_operator(self, node, children):
        _, operator, *_ = node
        return operator

    def visit_term(self, node, children):
        child = children[0]
        if isinstance(child, list):
            _, factor, *_ = child
            return factor
        else:
            return child

    def visit_factor(self, node, children):
        return self.calc(children)

    def calc(self, params):
        """ Calculates the actual equation. """
        x, op, y = params
        op = op.text

        if not isinstance(x, float):
            x = float(x.text)
        if not isinstance(y, float):
            y = float(y.text)

        if op == "+":
            return x+y
        elif op == "-":
            return x-y
        elif op == "/":
            return x/y
        elif op == "*":
            return x*y

equations = ["6 *(2+3)", "2+2", "4*8", "123-23", "-1+1", "100/10", "6**6"]

c = SimpleCalculator()
for equation in equations:
    try:
        tree = grammar.parse(equation)
        result = c.visit(tree)
        print("{} = {}".format(equation, result))
    except ParseError:
        print("The equation {} could not be parsed.".format(equation))
```

This yields

```
6 *(2+3) = 30.0
2+2 = 4.0
4*8 = 32.0
123-23 = 100.0
The equation -1+1 could not be parsed.
100/10 = 10.0
The equation 6**6 could not be parsed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correct data structures and algorithms to achieve your goal to parse a mathematical equation and evaluate it.
also you have to be familiar with two concepts: ***stacks*** and ***trees*** for creating a parser.

think the best algorithm you can use is [RPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (Reverse Polish Notation).

Answer (score 0):

For issue #1, you could always strip out the parentheses before evaluating.

```
input_string = "6*(2+3)"
it = filter(lambda x: x != '(' and x != ')', input_string)
after = ' '.join(list(it))
print(after)

# prints "6 * 2 + 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might just be starting to use python.  There are always many ways to solve a problem.  One interesting one to sort of get you jump started would be to consider splitting the equation based on the operators.

For example the following uses what's called a regular expression to split the formula:

```
import re
>>> formula2 = '6+3+5--5'
>>> re.split(r'\*|\/|\%|\^|\+|\-',formula2)
['6', '3', '5', '', '5']
>>> formula3 = '-2+5'
>>> re.split(r'\*|\/|\%|\^|\+|\-',formula3)
['', '2', '5']
```

It may look complex, but in the `r'\*|\/|\%|\^|\+|\-'` piece the \ means to take the next character literally and the | means 'or' so it evaluates to split on any one of those operators.

In this case you'd notice that any time there are two operators together, or when a formula starts with an operator you will have a blank value in your list - one for the second - in the first formula and one for the leading - in the second formula.

Based on that you could say something like:

```
if '' in re.split(r'\*|\/|\%|\^|\+|\-',formula):
     correctsign = False
```

Maybe this can serve as a good starting point to get the brain thinking about interesting ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Important to first mention that `**` stands for exponentiation, i.e `6**8`: 6 to the power of 8.

The logic behind your algorithm is wrong because in your code the response depends only on whether the last digit/sign satisfies your conditions. This is because once the loop is complete, your boolean `correctsigns` defaults to `True` or `False` based on the last digit/sign.

You can also use `elif` instead of nested `else` statements for cleaner code.

Without changing your core algorithm, your code would like something like this:

```
def checksigns(equation):
    signs = ["*","/","%","^","+","-"]
    for i in signs:
        if i in equation:
            index = equation.index((i))
            if (equation[index] == equation[0]):
                return "Not correct"
            elif (equation[index] == equation[len(equation) - 1]):
                return "Not correct"
            elif (equation[index + 1].isdigit() and equation[index - 1].isdigit()):
                return "Correct"
            else:
                return "Not correct"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module for parsing the expression:

```
import ast
import itertools as it

def check(expr):
    allowed = (ast.Add, ast.Sub, ast.Mult, ast.Mod)
    try:
        for node in it.islice(ast.walk(ast.parse(expr)), 2, None):
            if isinstance(node, (ast.BinOp, ast.Num)):
                continue
            if not isinstance(node, allowed):
                return False
    except SyntaxError:
        return False
    return True

print(check('6**8'))     # False
print(check('-6+2'))     # False
print(check('6*(2+3)'))  # True
```

The first case `6**8` evaluates as `False` because it is represented by `ast.Pow` node and the second one because `-6` corresponds to `ast.UnaryOp`.